# Overwritten HOME Variable

Tags: bash, unix, tilde-expansion

I recently learned that ~ refers to the HOME variable. So, if I set HOME=/foo and then try to use a bash script that would like to cd ~/Documents it ends up saying:

foo/Documents: No such file or directory

What's best practice in this situation? Crash and complain to the user that they overwrote HOME? Or is there some way to recover the default value of HOME?

Comment: It depends on the context. For many tools, the environment variables form part of the interface (e.g. `LC_*` and locales) and you want to allow the user to set them explicitly. In other cases like `sudo` you want to purge the environment to prevent unexpected things from happening. What are you doing with your script?

Comment: If they change `HOME`, that means they want applications to treat that directory as their home directory. It's not your responsibility to override their wishes.

Comment: The other recovery option would be to use `$USER` to test for `/home/$USER` in the standard location(s) and have that available if you did want to restore `$HOME`. Now understand, none of this can be done within a script and affect the shell. You can change the environment for the process run by the script, but not the parent. So if the user changes `$HOME` within a script, go with @Barmar's comment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: There is no guarantee that home directories actually live under `/home`.  While there are relatively few systems that still put it under `/usr/`, they are still in use.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's OS-specific, on OS X it's `/Users/$USER`.

Comment: They can also overwrite `$USER`

Comment: @Barmar: You can still use the real and effective UIDs from `id` or `whoami`... though a root-equivalent user could fake those out too.  At some point you give up and say "good enough."

Comment: I just saw the `bash` and `unix` tags. Agree that home can be anywhere, thus `"in the standard location(s)"` was added. If they also overwrite `USER` along with `HOME`, they are just out of luck for help from my comment.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I wanted to hear more general solutions so I was purposefully vague in the question. In brief, my current use case is setting up directory structures to setup an analysis environment (or perform analysis "cleanly"). But that's just the current case; I modify my scripts pretty regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just treat this like any other problem accessing files. If the file you're trying to access doesn't exist, or you're trying to create a file in the directory and you can't, you print an error message. If it's critical to the operation of the application, you exit after reporting the error.

As far as I'm aware, most applications that need to use the user's home directory just use the `HOME` environment variable, they don't try to second guess it.

There shouldn't be any security implication of this. The user still needs appropriate permission to access the files, so redirecting `HOME` won't allow them to write someone else's files that they shouldn't. If your application is set-uid, it should always revert back to the user's ID when opening files in the user's directory, not use the elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The source of truth for the user's home directory is `/etc/passwd`, which contains a line for every user on the system, listing the user's name, home directory, and some other information.  If your question is "what is so-and-so's home directory?", then you should look it up in `/etc/passwd`.*

However, while `/etc/passwd` is correct, if the user has clobbered `$HOME` with some other path, they may want you to use that value instead of the "real" home directory.  Unless there's a security problem with allowing the user to spoof the home directory, it may be preferable to blindly use the value given by the user.

Personally, I would check whether `$HOME` is a directory (e.g. with `if [[ -d "$HOME" ]]`), and if so, use it as is.  If not, parse it out of [`/etc/passwd`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd) using `grep` and `cut`, perhaps with a warning printed to stderr to remind the user that their `$HOME` is bad.  You can grep for the UID printed by `id -u`, which cannot be clobbered by a non-root user.

If you're really going to worry about `$HOME` being clobbered, however, you should also worry about `$PATH`, the `$LC_*` variables, and several other environment variables which can break various things.  Ultimately, it's easier to just assume these variables are correct and use them as-is, unless there is a security concern.  That would mean **just blindly use `$HOME` and don't worry too much about it being wrong.**

* On systems which are using LDAP or a similar networked system to manage accounts, the user's account might not be listed there.  In some cases, there's an `/etc/passwd.cache` or something similar, which may contain the user, but this is not guaranteed to work on every system.  Running `strace(1)` on `whoami(1)` can help indicate where this information is coming from.

Comment: Which line in `/etc/passwd`? They can overwrite `$USER` and `$LOGNAME`, too.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: There can be multiple users with the same uid. The username is used at login time to select the desired `/etc/passwd` line. I think `whoami` looks in `/var/run/utmp` to find the username associated with the current terminal.

Comment: @Barmar: I wrote that before I saw your comment which was why I deleted my comment before you responded.

Comment: @Barmar: I `strace`'d `whoami` and don't see any evidence of it opening any file under `/var`.  I'm pretty sure you actually *can't* have multiple users with the same UID without violating POSIX.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any documentation that confirms or denies that. I seem to recall systems that had multiple superuser accounts with different names, in the days before `sudo` became a standard tool.